# Getting NumberFormatException while getting the value in JSP using JSTL

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, jstl

I am working on Spring/Hibernate sample web application. Actually, I am trying to load the employees from database. In this case, while getting the data from database for both employee and address tables i am getting the NumberFormat exception.

Following is the code i am working on,

JSP Code:

```
      <c:if  test="${!empty employeeList}">
        <table class="data">
<c:forEach items="${employeeList}" var="emp">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${emp.firstname}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${emp.lastname}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${emp.email}" /></td>
        <td><a href="edit/${emp.id}">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a href="delete/${emp.id}">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Controller Code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listEmployees(ModelMap map) 
{
    map.addAttribute("employeeList", employeeManager.getAllEmployees());
    return "editEmployeeList";
}
```

Service Layer Code:

```
 @Override
@Transactional
public List<EmployeeEnitity> getAllEmployees() {
    return employeeDAO.getAllEmployees();
}


public List<EmployeeEntity> getAllEmployees() {
    return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select ee.firstname,ee.lastname,addr.email from " +
            "com.howtodoinjava.entity.EmployeeEntity ee, com.howtodoinjava.entity.AddressEntity addr where ee.id=addr.id").list();

}
```

Please help me to resolve this exception

Comment: What is the stack trace of the exception? Why don't you use generic types (i.e. List<Employee> instead of List). Do you really think employeeManager.getAllEmployees() returns a list of Strings? Why do you use SQL instead of HQL?

Comment: Actually, i am using one to one mapping that's why i didn't use generic's.I have two entities like EmployeeEntity, AddressEntity. I tried by using HQL but i am getting some HQL syntax error so i used Native SQL. Ofcourse it;s returning list o strings, i checked using toString() method.

Comment: Why would using OneToOne prevent you from using generics? Why not fix the syntax error instead of using SQL? `toString()` transforms any object into a String, so I don't see how it proves that the query returns Strings. It doesn't. And you've still not provided the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "firstname"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.coerce(ArrayELResolver.java:166)
 at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:46)
 at org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:104)
 at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
 at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)

Comment: added the stacktrace. I used generics too. This is the latest code i edited to apply the generis.  public List<String> getAllEmployees() {
  /*return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(listEmp).list();*/

Comment: Check what your query returns. It doesn't return a List<String>. It doesn't return a List<Employee> either. It returns a List<Object[]>. It would return a List<Employee if you used a simple HQL query: `select e from Employee e`.

Comment: actually, i have one more doubt. How to check whether the list returns string or not. I had checked using List<Object[]> it's returning the values like [john,steve,mark].

Comment: Use a debugger. Or use `System.out.println(list.get(0).getClass())`.

Comment: I can get the values without exception if i use the generics as employee with HQL. But, i wanna to retrieve from both tables employee and address. So, in this case i am getting error. Shall i use the generics as String.

Comment: Your view doesn't show any field from the address. Why do you want it loaded? Anyway, if you read the documentation of HQL, you would learn that this is done using a fetch join: `select e from Employee e left join fetch e.address`.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of [session.createQuery(String).list()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#list()) in your service method `getAllEmployees` is `List<Object[]>`, it is not `List<Employee>`

In controller you are adding this `List<Object[]>` to your model at this line:

```
map.addAttribute("employeeList",employeeList);
```

Now in JSP you are trying to access the model object in JSTL `forEach` loop:

```
<c:forEach items="${employeeList}" var="emp">
```

As `employeeList` represents `List<Object[]>`, the variable `emp` represents `Object[]`, it is not `Employee`. Now using `dot (.)` operator on variable `emp` means you are trying to access an element at a particular index position. For example:

```
emp.0 --> is same as emp[0]
emp.1 --> is same as emp[1]
emp.indexPosition --> is same as emp[indexPosition]
```

So when you say `emp.firstName`, then the `firstName` is converted to integer, as `firstName` is not an integer you are getting `NumberFormatException`

Comment: Ohhhh...i can get you. To get the value in jsp using jstl i can use like that only right....Can you tell me the way to resolve the error...

Comment: You understood the reason for the issue right? Now to fix this you already have a relationship between Employee & Address then as suggested by JBNizet you can use HQL query and get the output of session.createQuery(String).list() as List<Employee> instead of List<Object[]> then the same JSP code will work for you.

Comment: I did like you said by adding the EmployeeEntity as generic type but still i am getting the same NumberFormatException.

Comment: Chaitanya, actually i can get the data's without exception from employeeentity when i try to get the value from two entities by applying join i am getting numberformatexception.

Comment: **please update your question** with details on what you have modified and what error you are getting after that with complete stacktrace.

Comment: Chaitanya, I had updated the question and code now i am using. Actually, i can get the data when i use the employeeentity like List<EmployeeEntity> without any join. HQL will be like following   String HQL="from employeeentity";

Comment: @DIVA, update your question with this - what error you are getting after that with complete stacktrace.