# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing [WEB-INF/views/person.jsp] at line [24]

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp

Trying to run the code from https://www.journaldev.com/3531/spring-mvc-hibernate-mysql-integration-crud-example-tutorial. Add functionality and listing works.but updating the data causes JSP error. 
below is the error log
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing [WEB- INF/views/person.jsp] at line [24]

```
        22: <form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="person">
        23: <table>
        24:     <c:if test="${!empty person.name}">
        25:     <tr>
        26:         <td>
        27:             <form:label path="id">


    Root Cause
        java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "name"
        java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
        java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
```

I'm not much experienced in JSP.so could'nt pin point to a particular  point,tried many solutions and think seems to be in passing input to the  field name.

My SQL table is named Person and is as given below

```
id      int(11)     PRIMARY Key auto_increment
name    varchar(20)             
country varchar(20)
```

Below is my complete JSP code for my form.

```
<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="person">
<table>
<c:if test="${!empty person.name}">
<tr>
    <td>
        <form:label path="id">
            <spring:message text="ID"/>
        </form:label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <form:input path="id" readonly="true" size="8"  disabled="true" />
        <form:hidden path="id" />
    </td> 
</tr>
</c:if>
<tr>
    <td>
        <form:label path="name">
            <spring:message text="Name"/>
        </form:label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <form:input path="name" />
    </td> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <form:label path="country">
            <spring:message text="Country"/>
        </form:label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <form:input path="country" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <c:if test="${!empty person.name}">
            <input type="submit"
                value="<spring:message text="Edit Person"/>" />
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${empty person.name}">
            <input type="submit"
                value="<spring:message text="Add Person"/>" />
        </c:if>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are sending a `Object[]` instead of your `Person` object.

Read more here [Getting NumberFormatException while getting the value in JSP using JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25834106/643500)

To fix it, before adding the attribute to the request, ensure you are passing the correct object type (Person)

```
final TypedQuery<Person> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT person.name from Person person", Person.class);
final List<Person> resultList = query.getResultList();
Person person = resultList.get(0);

map.addAttribute("person", person);
```

if this does not help, post your backend code